# Creating a game launcher

Tags: windows, programming-languages, download, data-synchronization

I would like to make a simple program that will be able to download and keep the files up to date. It will also need to start a .exe file to run a game.

So the question is what language should be used? I know different languages will have different pros and cons.

I have not been able to thing of a way to be able to download the files then when a update does come out update them?
This is just about updating a folder with documents and game files that needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

I personally haven't done anything like this, but I would suggest looking into c++ as your language. Whenever the game loads up you can do a phone home request where the updated files are and check if the user's copy is up to date. When it comes to updating files you will need to learn some network programming. I don't know if this helps, but C and C++ are very good languages to start with.